# In Mercurial, can obsolete changesets be forced to become not obsolete?

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial changesets with a successor are marked [obsolete](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangesetEvolution).

Can this marker be (forcefully) removed somehow?

After using `hg strip` to remove the successor, the original changeset is still marked as obsolete and extinct). `hg evolve` refuses to re-create the successor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! you can remove obsolescence markers now.  Perhaps it wasn't possible in 2015, when the question was asked.

The solution is in the Apr 18, 2018 answer from [user377178](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377178/user377178):  `hg --hidden debugobsolete --delete <revindex>`

Note that you do not use a changeset ID.  You must use an index number (at least, with Mercurial 4.1.3).  Run `hg --hidden debugobsolete --index` to get a list of changesets with obsolescence markers. Find the index of the changeset that you want to become non-obsolete, then run `hg --hidden debugobsolete --delete <revindex>` with the index substituted for *revindex*.  Then your obsolete changeset is no longer obsolete.  (It might be in the list multiple times--I have not thoroughly investigated.)

The debugobsolete command is currently not listed in the [evolve user guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html), even in the section on [recovering obsolete changesets](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#example-11-recover-an-obsolete-changeset).  However, it is listed in the [Evolve How To](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/evolve-faq.html) guide.

Many thanks to user377178.

Comment: "Find the index of the changeset that you want" is not completely obvious because it's not immediately clear how to read the output from `hg --hidden debugobsolete --index`.  The format appears to be: `index obsoleteHash replacementHash ...`, where `obsoleteHash` is the hash for the change you want to un-obsolete.

Answer (score 16):

You can't unmark a change as obsolete, but you can bring it back to life using "`hg touch <rev> --hidden`", where touch is a new command that is part of the [evolve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EvolveExtension).

FWIW. It's also possible to rebase the obsolete change, but you'll probably get fewer complications if you use touch.

Comment: Interesting. I tested with two obsolete changesets `2` and `3`. `hg touch 2::3 --hidden` brings back both as `4::5`. Just `hg touch 2 --hidden` and then `hg touch 3 --hidden` also brings them back as `4` and `5`, but `5` is not a descendant of `4`. For this reason (and the fact that `touch` is not available in TortoiseHG yet) I find rebase more convenient actually. Are there any specific complications with rebase to be aware of?

Comment: Also for anyone wondering what exactly `hg touch` does internally, `hg log --debug --hidden` shows it adds a `__touch-noise__=<somenumber>` `extra` property so the changeset hash is different even if all other changeset properties remain the same.

Comment: You should be able to add a custom toolbar command to THG which would call `touch`

Answer (score 3):

I have come up with the following bash function - a hack and likely dependents on mercurial version but has been working well for years. Takes revset as parameter.

```
function hg_unhide() {
  for i in $(hg --hidden  log --template '{node}\n' -r "$1"); do
    hg --hidden debugobsolete --index | grep $i | awk '{ print $1;}' | \
      xargs -r hg --hidden debugobsolete --delete
  done
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on a merge changeset, which the `hg touch` command in the other answer fails for (see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2015-March/066852.html )

Comment: The link to the `hg touch` bug is dead. The bug moved to https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4561

Answer (score 3):

The current [Mercurial documentation *Evolve: User Guide*](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/user-guide.html#example-11-recover-an-obsolete-changeset) has a discussion on this.

> ## Recover an obsolete changeset
>
> Sometimes you might obsolete a changeset, and then change your mind. You’ll probably start looking for an “unobsolete” command to restore a
> changeset to normal state. For complicated implementation reasons,
> *that command doesn’t exist*. ...
>
> Instead, evolve provides a `touch` command to resurrect an obsolete
> changeset.
>
> An unexpected quirk: you almost certainly need to use
> `--hidden`, since obsolete changesets tend to be hidden, and you can’t
> reference a hidden changeset otherwise.
>
> Typical usage thus looks like
>
> ```
> $ hg --hidden touch REV
> ```
>
> This creates a new, normal changeset which is the same as `REV`—except
> with a different changeset ID. The new changeset will have the same
> parent as `REV`, and will be a successor of `REV`.
>
> The current implementation of `hg touch` is not ideal, and is likely
> to change in the future. ...

(emphasis added)

---

That said, personally I have found it simpler to `graft` the obsolete changesets back into usage. You can do this easily in TortoiseHG for example by just selecting the obsoletes that you want and grafting them all in one batch. Grafting may technically work outside (or skirt around) the obsolescence system but given the complexities of using `touch` as alluded to above I find the simplicity worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The most current or maybe even "bleeding edge" approach to this seems to be using:

**`hg rewind`**

or its alias

**`hg undo`**

I say "bleeding edge" because although this command is released and seems to work, I can't find much documented about it, though the `hg` command line help does include it (below). It may still be considered *experimental* (as of 2022).

`hg rewind` seems potentially intended to replace `hg touch`.

---

Here's an example of it in use:

```
% hg rebase --dest=25707 --source=26017 
rebasing 26017:5c78e2af32cb "message 1"
rebasing 26018:f156002253b3 "message 2"
...
[command completed successfully Fri Apr 29 09:07:15 2022]

% hg rewind
rewound to 33 changesets
(33 changesets obsoleted)
working directory is now at 0ad018a90b93
```

The net effect of these commands were to leave things exactly equivalent to where I started. The `rewind` took about as long as the `rebase`.

---

Built in help states the following:

```
% hg undo --help
hg rewind [--as-divergence] [--exact] [--keep] [--to REV]... [--from REV]...

aliases: undo

rewind a stack of changesets to a previous state

    This command can be used to restore stacks of changesets to an obsolete
    state, creating identical copies.

    There are two main ways to select the rewind target. Rewinding "from"
    changesets will restore the direct predecessors of these changesets (and
    obsolete the changeset you rewind from). Rewinding "to" will restore the
    changeset you have selected (and obsolete their latest successors).

    By default, we rewind from the working directory parents, restoring its
    predecessor.

    ...


% hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 5.9.2)
...
```

Importantly, the help also includes the following cautions:

> **Current rough edges:**
>
> - fold: rewinding to only some of the initially folded changesets
>   will
>   be problematic. The fold result is marked obsolete and the part not
>   rewinded to are "lost".  Please use --as-divergence when you need to
>   perform such operation.
> - 'hg rewind' might affect changesets outside the current stack.
>   Without
>   --exact, we also restore ancestors of the rewind target, obsoleting
>   their latest successors (unless --as-divergent is provided). In some
>   case, these latest successors will be on branches unrelated to the
>   changeset you rewind from. (We plan to automatically detect this case
>   in the future)

---

Some Mercurial developer-oriented notes about `rewind` are:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CEDConcept
- https://octobus.net/blog/2018-09-03-evolve-status-2018-08.html
- https://www.mail-archive.com/evolve-testers@mercurial-scm.org/msg00052.html